# Remove elements from RDD starting with certain character

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I am working with an RDD which has few lines which start with #.
I want to remove all these lines which begin with # and keep remaining ones. 
I tried remove = records.filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith('#')) but this way it filters only the rows containing #. I want the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting your condition:

```
records.filter(lambda x: not x[0].startswith('#'))
```

Comment: great answer. I applied this idea to my rdd (i.e. `data1_filt`, via PySpark Databricks) `foo = data1_filt.filter(lambda word: not word.startswith('a'))`

Comment: note that rdd was an output rdd from `flatmap`